# Why does closure cause memory leak in JavaScript in this case?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have this following code snippet:

```js
function outer() {
  let a

  return function inner() {
    
     a = new Uint8Array(100000)
     const b = new Uint16Array(100000)
  };
};
const fn = outer(); 
fn()
```

Took one heap snapshot, ran it in a about:blank page in chrome 103.0.5060.114, and took a second snapshot. Comparing the two snapshots, I found that in the second snapshot, there is **one more `Uint8Array`**. That means `a` is retained in memory, so it **leaked**. But I can't find any `Uint16Array` so `b` didn't leak.
[image]
[image]

But I couldn't figure out why that `Uint8Array` is leaking because it doesn't seem like I can still reference it outside the `outer` function. So According to the garbage collection algorithm, it should have been collected by now.

Haven't tested this in other browsers or in Node.

Comment: `a` is retained because it is used by `inner`. `inner==fn`. If you delete `fn` I assume `a` will be gone.

Comment: @ITgoldman well `b` is also used by `inner` but it didn't get leaked. Plus I didn't return either so they are both **unreachable** from outside and thus should be all GC'ed.

Comment: `b` is irrelevant because it is just a local variable, gone when the function ends. however `a` exists while the function exists. He is bound to it or the other way.

Comment: well, no, once `a` finishes executing, there is no way to reach to `a` anymore. it should have been GC'ed

Comment: Private variables are also unreachable. That is not the test for GC. I do see some weirdness bcz `a` is overwritten. Nevertheless while `fn` exists `inner` exists (they are the same object. `fn.toString()` and see) and while `inner` exists it refers/uses/needs/bound to `a` so there is a use for it, and good that it hadn't been GC`ed.

Comment: can you show me how this is useful? maybe show me how you manage to get `a` from `inner` once it finishes executing?

Comment: In `fn` / `inner` `a` is a free variable so `a` will not be GC-ed unless the scope where `fn` is created goes out. If its global then it will never be GC-ed.

Comment: but there is no way you can retrieve `a` outside `fn` / `inner` right? if not then `a` isn't not reachable isn't it?

Comment: @Joji The variable `a` is still referenced (closed over) by `fn`/`inner`, which is reachable  (alive) itself, so it won't get garbage-collected. That there exists no code that can retrieve (read from) `a`, or - in more complicated cases - that all code that does retrieve `a` is [not reachable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code) from the current state of the program and won't be executed, is not taken into account by the garbage collector. This would require advanced program analysis techniques, and [is not generally decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: thanks! @Bergi can you please expound on this advanced program analysis a little more? Is there any garbage collector out there that has this optimization baked in?

Comment: Consider `function cell(val) { let locked=false; return {write(x){ if(!locked) val=x; }, read(){ if(!locked) return val; }, lock() { locked=true; }}; }`. If you do `const c = cell(); c.write(new Uint8Array(100000)); c.lock();`, then `val` is still referenced from the `c.write` and `c.read` closures, even though there is no way to access it any more since the cell is "locked". No garbage collector (that I know of, maybe there are some research ones) is capable of detecting such things, collecting `val` when `lock()` is called. (And in theory, with a debugger, you could reset `locked=false`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ITgoldman's explanation is right: `a` is retained because `inner` uses it, and `fn === inner`, and `fn` is still reachable. This is not a leak.

`a` can be reached again after `fn()` finishes simply by calling `fn()` again. `b` is just a local variable, so it goes out of scope when `fn()` returns.

An example how this is useful/required: consider the following slight modification of your snippet:

```
function outer() {
  let a = 0;

  return function inner() {
    a++;
    console.log(`counter is now ${a}`);
  };
};
const fn = outer(); 
fn()
fn()
fn()
```

Clearly, `a` should remain alive from one invocation of `fn()` to the next, so it can't be collected.

It doesn't matter whether `inner`/`fn` reads from `a`, writes to `a`, or does both. As long as it *uses* `a` in any way, `a` will remain alive as long as `fn` is alive. This makes sense because there could be more than one function referring to it: you could have `inner1` allocating new arrays and storing them in `a`, and `inner2` doing stuff with these arrays.

(This is not a V8 question; all spec-compliant JavaScript engines are required to behave like this.)

Comment: got it. there are many posts claiming closure causes memory leaks... are they just wrong?

Comment: Any post claiming that your example is a memory leak is wrong, yes. It's required behavior.

Comment: interesting... but if I tried `outer()()` instead of `const fn = outer(); fn()` then there is no `a` retained according to the heap snapshot. Is this also by design?

Comment: Yes. As I said, `fn` keeps `a` alive. If there is no `fn`, `a` is cleaned up.

Comment: thanks. btw is this old thread related to this question? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315190

Comment: Related in that it's about JS closures; unrelated in that it describes a different situation.

Comment: @jmrk Well I guess technically an engine could optimise away write-only variables and avoid the memory retention that way, but it's not worth the optimisation efforts since such badly written code is not common - pointing out and removing write-only variables is (should be) done by a linter when the code is written, not when it's executed.

Comment: is write-only here referring to `a` inside `fn`/`inner`?

Comment: @Bergi for such simple cases, yes, whole-program analysis could find and remove write-only references. But (1) in the general case (i.e. for arbitrarily complicated situations), that  would require solving the halting problem, (2) whole-program analysis is generally not something that JS engines do (because of high cost and limited usefulness), (3) as you already say, this should be rare in practice and (at least for the limited cases where it can be done at all) can be done by offline linters.

Comment: are there linting rules that can prevent such usages?

Comment: @Joji A quick search like google.com/search?q=javascript+write-only+variable+lint finds e.g. https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars, there are probably many others too.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually, a Lexical Environment is removed from memory with all the
> variables after the function call finishes. That’s because there are
> no references to it. As any JavaScript object, it’s only kept in
> memory while it’s reachable.
>
> However, if there’s a nested function that is still reachable after
> the end of a function, then it has [[Environment]] property that
> references the lexical environment.

You can more about how garbage collection works in closures [here](https://javascript.info/closure#garbage-collection).